# Why does a type being trivially default constructible improve performance in some situations?

Tags: c++, c++20

Consider these three classes:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    // causes default ctor to be deleted
    constexpr explicit Foo(int i) noexcept : _i(i) {} 
private:
    int _i;
};

// same as Foo but default ctor is brought back and explicitly defaulted
struct Bar
{
    constexpr Bar() noexcept = default;
    constexpr explicit Bar(int i) noexcept : _i(i) {}

private:
    int _i;
};

// same as Bar but member variable uses brace-or-equals initializer (braces in this case)
struct Baz
{
    constexpr Baz() noexcept = default;
    constexpr explicit Baz(int i) noexcept : _i(i) {}

private:
    int _i{};
};
```

The following `static_assert`s evaluate to true (C++20):

```cpp
static_assert(not std::is_trivially_default_constructible_v<Foo>);
static_assert(std::is_trivially_default_constructible_v<Bar>);
static_assert(not std::is_trivially_default_constructible_v<Baz>);
```

meaning that only Bar is considered to be trivially default constructible.

I understand how `Foo` and `Baz` don't meet the condition as far the standard's definition goes, but what I don't understand is why does this mean that certain algorithms can optimize operations on `Bar` in ways that they can't do so on `Foo` or `Baz`.

Example of runtime test showcasing the benefits of being trivially default constructible:  https://quick-bench.com/q/t1W4ItmCoJ60U88_ED9s_7I9Cl0

The test populates a vector with 1000 randomly generated objects and measures the runtime of doing so. Ran with `int`, `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz`. My guess is the vector reallocations and copying/moving of the objects is where the difference in performance manifests itself.

**What is it about being trivially default constructible that enables optimizations?**

**Why was the compiler (or the std::vector implementation) unable to apply the same optimization on `Foo` and `Baz`?**

Comment: non-trivial types must be constructed while trivial types, that are also implicit lifetime types, don't need to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a missed optimization for gcc.

Basically, the question is: when `vector` has to reallocate, how do you transfer the elements from the old storage to the new storage?
gcc's implementation [currently](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/0f3b4d38d4bad8994150fe7a1e5428055d29a4bf/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_uninitialized.h#L1076-L1130) tries to do this (I removed some irrelevant blocks of code for brevity):

```cpp
  // This class may be specialized for specific types.
  // Also known as is_trivially_relocatable.
  template<typename _Tp, typename = void>
    struct __is_bitwise_relocatable
    : is_trivial<_Tp> { };

  template <typename _InputIterator, typename _ForwardIterator,
        typename _Allocator>
    _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
    inline _ForwardIterator
    __relocate_a_1(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
           _ForwardIterator __result, _Allocator& __alloc)
    noexcept(noexcept(std::__relocate_object_a(std::addressof(*__result),
                           std::addressof(*__first),
                           __alloc)))
    {
      _ForwardIterator __cur = __result;
      for (; __first != __last; ++__first, (void)++__cur)
    std::__relocate_object_a(std::__addressof(*__cur),
                 std::__addressof(*__first), __alloc);
      return __cur;
    }

  template <typename _Tp, typename _Up>
    _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
    inline __enable_if_t<std::__is_bitwise_relocatable<_Tp>::value, _Tp*>
    __relocate_a_1(_Tp* __first, _Tp* __last,
           _Tp* __result,
           [[__maybe_unused__]] allocator<_Up>& __alloc) noexcept
    {
      ptrdiff_t __count = __last - __first;
      if (__count > 0)
    {
      __builtin_memmove(__result, __first, __count * sizeof(_Tp));
    }
      return __result + __count;
    }
```

The first overload here does a member-wise copy, the second overload does a single `memmove` - but only if the type satisfies `__is_bitwise_relocatable<_Tp>`, which as you can see defaults to `std::is_trivial`. `std::is_trivial` *requires* a trivial default constructor, which isn't actually relevant for this particular optimization (see [#68350](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68350), but that's what's causing the code path to do the slow element-wise copy instead of the single memmove.

You can verify this is the case by specializing `__is_bitwise_relocatable<Foo>` and seeing that the performance [now lines up](https://quick-bench.com/q/GBvOUffzsSKe3y3zZpiaBC5L1Tg).

Comment: Now this makes sense! You pointed out the missed opportunity in gcc in this particular case. However, are there any other situation where having a trivially default constructible type _is_ beneficial for performance reasons? Sounds like it should ever really matter during construction (as in contexts unrelated to relocatability)

Comment: Also, my guess is the program is _technically_ in UB land if someone were to truly specialize is_bitwise_relocatable... right?

Comment: @supernun If you're default (not value) constructing a bunch of things, then sure having it be trivially default constructible would matter. Dunno when that really happens though. And why would a program be _technically_ UB if you specialize it (... for a type that is actually bitwise relocatable)? There's even a comment in front of it saying you can specialize it.

Comment: _"why would a program be technically UB if you specialize it"._ Mostly because that condition shows up for other similar type traits (e.g., https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable where it says _"The behavior of a program that adds specializations for is_trivially_copyable or is_trivially_copyable_v is undefined."_

Comment: @supernun Sure, you can't specialize that one, but you can specialize this one.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand how Foo and Baz don't meet the condition as far the standard's definition goes, but what I don't understand is why does this mean that certain algorithms can optimize operations on Bar in ways that they can't do so on Foo or Baz.

This is *not* real implementation, but merely a conceptual hint at it:

```
Bar* default_alloc_x_Bars(int x)
{
    return (Bar*)(char*)malloc(sizeof(Bar)*x); //returns nullptr if allocation unsuccesful
}

Baz* default_alloc_x_Bazs(int x)
{
    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(Baz)*x);

    if(buffer)
        memset((void*)buffer,0,sizeof(Baz)*x);

    return (Baz*)buffer; //returns nullptr if allocation unsuccesful
}
```

It is impossible to create a legal `Baz` or `Foo` where `_i` is uninitialized, so you cannot simply take a chunk of memory and declare that it's a `Baz`/`Foo`.

`Bar` does *not* initialize `_i` so any given chunk of memory with the correct size and alignment is, functionally, a `Bar`.

(There are intricacies to this, you cannot simply cast memory around like we're writing plain C, but as a conceptual model for why trivial construction matters, this is pretty much the whole of the thing)

Comment: How does this lead to any kind of additional work by std::vector? In my testbench, I'm not creating any defaulted `Baz`/`Foo` objects. However, the vector is likely reserving additional space when `size() == capacity()` but that shouldn't count as default constructing anything (unless I'm wrong about this last sentence...)

Comment: "_It is impossible to create a legal Baz or Foo where _i is uninitialized, so you cannot simply take a chunk of memory and declare that it's a Baz/Foo._": That's actually not the case. That the type has a trivial copy constructor and a trivial non-deleted destructor is actually sufficient to do exactly that. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Implicit-lifetime_class.

Comment: @user17732522 re: your first comment - how are you going to use a trivial copy ctor and default dtor to create a Foo or Baz with an uninitialized _i?

Comment: @SRNissen You don't need to. They may exist with uninitialized value, implicitly created without constructor call. Also, if the type is not implicit-lifetime, then `memeset` doesn't help either. You need explicit placement-`new`s in that case. But either way that scenario is not relevant to the benchmark OP is presenting.

Comment: @user17732522 reading through P0593R6 you're right that it's an implicit lifetime class - that cannot be implicitly created if you read from uninitialized _i because implicit lifetime only happens if it would render the program's behavior defined, which it won't be if you read from the uninitialized _i.

Comment: @SRNissen Yes, the object can't be read from, but it is still there (if it would prevent  the program having UB) and can e.g. be written to. In any case it is not relevant to std::vector which should be able to be implemented with equal performance for all of OP's types. In the new answer Barry tracked down where libstdc++ is applying the optimization too restrictively.

Comment: There is no zeroing of memory going on here.